# Is $[0,2\pi)$ a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, curves

If $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $\phi:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{S^2}$ defined by $\phi(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ then $\phi$ is a bijective and continuous function.

Applying the following proposition to $\phi$

$$\text{$f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of a closed set by $f$ is a closed set}$$

can I conclude that $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{S^2})=[0,2\pi)$ is a closed set?

Comment: It is indeed closed under the subspace topology of $[0,2\pi)$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Closed with respect to what topology exactly?

Comment: @DerekAllums Euclidean Topology

Comment: Don't forget that you are considering your interval $[0,2\pi)$ as a set on its own and not as a subset of something larger.

Comment: I meant as a slight hint which is elaborated in the answer below. I think maybe your confusion arises from the desire to think of it as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ rather than a non proper subspace of itself, with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I edited the question to change $cos(t)$ and $sin(t)$ to $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t).$ Adding a backslash does not only prevent italicization, but also results in context-dependent spacing, so that there is more space to the right of $\sin$ in $\sin t$ than in $\sin(t),$ without any manual editing of the spacing, and there is more space before and after $\sin$ in $5\sin t$ (coded as `5\sin t`) then in $5\text{sin}t$ (coded as `5\text{sin}t`). $\qquad$

Comment: That is S1 not S2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, clearly $[0,2\pi)$ is closed (and open) in the space $[0,2\pi)$ which is the domain of your function. $X$ is always closed in $X$.

Comment: can we define continuous functions in $S\subset X$ and using the topology defined in $X$ or we definitely have to work with the subspace topology of $S$?

Comment: @Gio it comes down to the same thing in the end, as the subspace topology is defined in terms of the topology on $X$. But the fact you quoted was for the topology on the domain, not of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

$[0,2\pi)$ is clearly *not* a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, since it has a boundary point that is not one of its members, namely $2\pi.$

But it is closed as a subset of the space consisting only of $[0,2\pi).$ The point $2\pi$ does not exist within that space and so cannot be a boundary point within that space of any set within that space.

Look up the term "subspace topology." A space whose points are the members of $[0,2\pi)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R$ if the subspace topology is assigned to it.